# non-periodic function $e^{-\pi i x}$

Tags: periodic-functions

How would you prove $e^{-\pi ix}$ $\forall x \in \Re$ is not 1-periodic?

The Definition of 1-periodic function is:
$f : \Re \to \Im$ be 1-periodic if $f(x+1) = f(x)$ $\forall x \in \Re$

What I have been able to do is:

$e^{-\pi i(x+1)} = e^{-\pi ix}$

$e^{-\pi ix}e^{-\pi 1i}$ = $e^{-\pi ix}$

$e^{-\pi 1i}$ = $e^{0}$

$e^{-\pi 1i}$ = $1$

I don't know how to proceed further or argue why this can't be 1-periodic.
I have looked at Euler's formula but was not sure how to use it here.

Thanks

Comment: Calculate the lefthandside, realize it is -1 and you have a contradiction

Comment: @includeCMath Thanks I would use euler's formula to calculate lefthandside, is that correct to use here?

Comment: Yes you could use it here.

Comment: @includeCMath Thanks